# Why is this CoreData fetch so slow?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

```
CoreData: sql:
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCLIENTCREATEDAT, t0.ZCLIENTUPDATEDAT, t0.ZCREATEDAT, t0.ZDATERAISED, t0.ZID, t0.ZLOCKVERSION, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSEQUENCENUMBER, t0.ZTYPE, t0.ZUPDATEDAT, t0.ZUUID, t0.ZVSYNCSTATUS, t0.ZVVERSION, t0.ZVVERSIONSTATUS, t0.ZCREATEDBY, t0.ZDATA, t0.ZOWNEDBY, t0.ZPROJECT, t0.ZPROJECTCOMPANY, t0.ZTEMPLATE, t0.ZWBSITEM, t0.ZACTIONTYPE, t0.ZSTATUS, t0.ZCOMPANY, t0.ZCLOSEDREASON, t0.ZDOCUMENTDATA, t0.ZSMARKWHENREADYTOSEND, t0.ZSPDFSYNCSTATUS, t0.ZSTATUS1, t0.ZAUTHORISATIONCODE, t0.ZBCCRECEIVED, t0.ZRECIPIENTEMAIL, t0.ZRECIPIENTNAME, t0.ZRFIRESPONSESTATUS
FROM ZBASEFORM t0
WHERE ((( t0.ZVVERSIONSTATUS = ? OR ( t0.ZVVERSIONSTATUS = ? AND  t0.ZVSYNCSTATUS = ?) OR ( t0.ZVVERSIONSTATUS = ? AND  t0.ZVSYNCSTATUS = ?)) AND  t0.ZPROJECT = ?) AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?)
ORDER BY t0.ZDATERAISED DESC, t0.ZCLIENTCREATEDAT DESC

CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 1.7336s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 1.7462s for 1868 rows.
```

The table has only 1975 rows and I am fetching 1868 of them.

I copied the database from device to desktop and did `sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and got this beast.

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     105   0                    00               
1     SorterOpen     1     40    0     k(2,-B,-B)     00               
2     OpenRead       0     8     0     37             00               
3     OpenRead       2     76    0     k(2,,)         02               
4     Integer        7     1     0                    00               
5     SeekGE         2     60    1     1              00               
6       IdxGT          2     60    1     1              00               
7       Seek           2     0     0                    00               
8       Column         0     8     2                    00               
9       Eq             3     16    2     (BINARY)       44               
10      Ne             5     13    2     (BINARY)       54               
11      Column         0     6     4                    00               
12      Eq             6     16    4     (BINARY)       44               
13      Ne             5     59    2     (BINARY)       54               
14      Column         0     6     4                    00               
15      Ne             7     59    4     (BINARY)       54               
16      Column         0     12    4                    00               
17      Ne             8     59    4     (BINARY)       54               
18      Column         2     0     11                   00               
19      IdxRowid       2     12    0                    00               
20      Column         0     2     13                   00               
21      Column         0     24    14                   00               
22      Column         0     25    15                   00               
23      Column         0     26    16                   00               
24      Column         0     27    17                   00               
25      Column         0     3     18                   00               
26      Column         0     4     19                   00               
27      Column         0     29    20                   00               
28      Column         0     5     21                   00               
29      Column         0     30    22                   00               
30      Column         0     28    23                   00               
31      Column         0     31    24                   00               
32      Column         0     6     25                   00               
33      Column         0     7     26                   00               
34      Column         0     8     27                   00               
35      Column         0     9     28                   00               
36      Column         0     10    29                   00               
37      Column         0     11    30                   00               
38      Column         0     12    31                   00               
39      Column         0     13    32                   00               
40      Column         0     14    33                   00               
41      Column         0     15    34                   00               
42      Column         0     32    35                   00               
43      Column         0     16    36                   00               
44      Column         0     17    37                   00               
45      Column         0     18    38                   00               
46      Column         0     36    39                   00               
47      Column         0     19    40                   00               
48      Column         0     20    41                   00               
49      Column         0     21    42                   00               
50      Column         0     33    43                   00               
51      Column         0     22    44                   00               
52      Column         0     34    45                   00               
53      Column         0     35    46                   00               
54      Column         0     23    47                   00               
55      Copy           17    9     0                    00               
56      Copy           14    10    0                    00               
57      MakeRecord     9     39    48                   00               
58      SorterInsert   1     48    0                    00               
59    Next           2     6     1                    00               
60    Close          0     0     0                    00               
61    Close          2     0     0                    00               
62    OpenPseudo     3     49    40                   00               
63    SorterSort     1     104   0                    00               
64      SorterData     1     49    3                    00               
65      Column         3     2     11                   00               
66      Column         3     3     12                   00               
67      Column         3     4     13                   00               
68      Column         3     5     14                   00               
69      Column         3     6     15                   00               
70      Column         3     7     16                   00               
71      Column         3     8     17                   00               
72      Column         3     9     18                   00               
73      Column         3     10    19                   00               
74      Column         3     11    20                   00               
75      Column         3     12    21                   00               
76      Column         3     13    22                   00               
77      Column         3     14    23                   00               
78      Column         3     15    24                   00               
79      Column         3     16    25                   00               
80      Column         3     17    26                   00               
81      Column         3     18    27                   00               
82      Column         3     19    28                   00               
83      Column         3     20    29                   00               
84      Column         3     21    30                   00               
85      Column         3     22    31                   00               
86      Column         3     23    32                   00               
87      Column         3     24    33                   00               
88      Column         3     25    34                   00               
89      Column         3     26    35                   00               
90      Column         3     27    36                   00               
91      Column         3     28    37                   00               
92      Column         3     29    38                   00               
93      Column         3     30    39                   00               
94      Column         3     31    40                   00               
95      Column         3     32    41                   00               
96      Column         3     33    42                   00               
97      Column         3     34    43                   00               
98      Column         3     35    44                   00               
99      Column         3     36    45                   00               
100     Column         3     37    46                   00               
101     Column         3     38    47                   00               
102     ResultRow      11    37    0                    00               
103   SorterNext     1     64    0                    00               
104   Halt           0     0     0                    00               
105   Transaction    0     0     188   0              01               
106   TableLock      0     8     0     ZBASEFORM      00               
107   Integer        1     3     0                    00               
108   Integer        2     5     0                    00               
109   Integer        4     6     0                    00               
110   Integer        5     7     0                    00               
111   Integer        3     8     0                    00               
112   Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

Comment: What does the fetch request look like?

Comment: I have eliminated the predicate completely now and it is still the same speed. So now it is just a pure object fetch with a sort on two date fields.

Comment: did you index your columns?

Comment: There is no index on the date fields, but with only 1900 rows I wouldn't expect it to matter.

Comment: could you please share the code of your fetch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the cause of the slowness.

One of the object properties was a NSData blob which apparently absolutely kills fetch sorting in CoreData. So watch out for that.

Comment: So it wasn't actually two date fields after all then, eh? :)

Comment: Well I was sorting on two date fields. The very existence of another large data field seems to just kill sqlite fetch sorting. A post fetch array sort worked in milliseconds.